# Will a $3\times 4$ matrix always span $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is the problem that was assigned:

> Give a counter example to show that the statement is false and explain
>   why it is false:
>
> If $A$ is a $3 \times 4$ matrix, then every $b\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a linear
>   combination of the columns of $A$.

From my understanding, given an $m \times n$ matrix, the matrix will always span $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $k$ is equal to the rank of the matrix.

Given that information, would the following matrix be a valid answer, given that the matrix only has a rank of 2?

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yes, because it doesn't span $\mathbb R^3$, but only a two dimensional subspace of it.

Comment: Sure, though you might as well just take $0$. (For clarity, I should also mention that the image of the matrix is a vector space of dimension $k$, not necessarily the specific copy of $\mathbb{R}^k$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$ as the first $k$ coordinates, or some similar fixed space.)

Comment: Just as a general working tip when you're looking for counter-examples it can often be useful to check the trivial or exceptional cases first.In this case the zero matrix proves to be such a counter-example.